# Find missing records between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume that I have two tables `tblA` and `tblDate` and I want to find missing records in `tblA` [Name, Date] i.e. where there is no row that matches a `tblDate` [Date].

Draft tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblA]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [Val] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDate] 
(
    [Date] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblA] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[tblA] ([Id], [Name], [Date], [Val])
VALUES
(3, N'A', CAST(N'2023-12-22' AS Date), N'data'),
(4, N'A', CAST(N'2023-12-23' AS Date), N'data'),
(5, N'B', CAST(N'2023-12-22' AS Date), N'data'),
(6, N'B', CAST(N'2023-12-23' AS Date), N'data'),
(7, N'A', CAST(N'2023-12-27' AS Date), N'data'),
(8, N'A', CAST(N'2023-12-28' AS Date), N'data')
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblA] OFF
GO

INSERT [dbo].[tblDate] ([Date])
VALUES
(CAST(N'2023-12-22' AS Date)),
(CAST(N'2023-12-23' AS Date)),
(CAST(N'2023-12-24' AS Date)),
(CAST(N'2023-12-25' AS Date)),
(CAST(N'2023-12-26' AS Date)),
(CAST(N'2023-12-27' AS Date)),
(CAST(N'2023-12-28' AS Date))
GO
```

Data

```
Id  Name    Date    Val
-------------------------
3   A   2023-12-22  data
4   A   2023-12-23  data
5   B   2023-12-22  data
6   B   2023-12-23  data
7   A   2023-12-27  data
8   A   2023-12-28  data
```

`tblDate`:

```
Date
----------
2023-12-22
2023-12-23
2023-12-24
2023-12-25
2023-12-26
2023-12-27
2023-12-28
```

Expected result

```
Name    Date
-------------------
A       2023-12-24
B       2023-12-24
A       2023-12-25
B       2023-12-25
A       2023-12-26
B       2023-12-26
B       2023-12-27
B       2023-12-28
```

I want the query to show only the missing dates and their name.
What I have tried.

```
select d.Date, a.Name
from dbo.tblDate d
full join dbo.tblA a on d.Date = a.Date
where a.Date is null
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the expected data, you need to get the missing data for each Date and Name (**A** and **B** in this case).

You can achieve this by employing a `CROSS JOIN` to generate a dataset with tblDate, wherein each record contains two names. Then, perform a left join with the table to obtain the missing records :

```
SELECT n.Name, d.[Date]
FROM tblDate d 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM tblA) n
LEFT JOIN tblA a ON d.[Date] = a.[Date] AND a.Name = n.Name
WHERE a.Id IS NULL
ORDER BY [Date], Name
```

Results :

```
Name    Date
A       2023-12-24
B       2023-12-24
A       2023-12-25
B       2023-12-25
A       2023-12-26
B       2023-12-26
B       2023-12-27
B       2023-12-28
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2w6QzQQZ)

Answer (score 1):

This is something that can be solved by doing a CROSS JOIN combined with a EXISTS.

Using your sample data:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    tblDate d
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  DISTINCT Name FROM  tblA
    ) a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT  1
    FROM    tblA aTarget
    WHERE   aTarget.name = a.Name
    AND aTarget.Date = d.Date
)
```

Explanation:
Since you want to gather unique names from table A that has data gaps, we first create unique combination of Name + Date by doing a CROSS JOIN. I use (SELECT DISTINCT) to only get the unique Name values.

Then you just check if this combination exists in the target table by doing a WHERE NOT EXISTS.